# Перевод из int в str всех элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, map

Нужно перевести все элементы списка из `int` в `str`.

Пример:

```
a = [1,2,3... ]       # список в int
b = ['1','2','3'... ] # как надо
```

Очень нужна помощь! Буду признателен!

Answer (score 4):

как вариант:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> b = list(map(str, a))
>>> 
>>> print(b)
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = [str(i) for i in a]
```

Применен *генератор списка* — для понимания нужно читать справа (`for i in a`) налево (`str(i)`).

Делает то же самое как код

```
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i)
```

(Вы можете применить его, когда он вам более нравиться.)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию map. Она пройдется по всем элементам вашего списка и применит заданную функцию к каждому из них.
Синтаксис:

map(функция_которую_надо_применить, список)

Кроме списка может использоваться любой итерируемый объект, например, кортеж.

После использования данной функции необходимо будет преобразовать объект обратно в список

В данном случае, это наиболее компактное решение, и в вашем случае оно будет выглядеть так:

```
b = list(map(str,a))
```

Так же вы можете пройтись по индексам списка при помощи цикла for:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(str(a[i]))
```